# QGIS - expression join attrributes by location

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, expression, geolocation

I'd like to sum up values from a point layer in my polygon layer from points lying within the polygon.
I only found it with the processing toolbox, but that creates a new layer. But I just want to make a new field in my polygon layer that updates when I place a new point.
My case: I have a polygon layer with many forests to plant and I want to calculate the number of trees to plant. I have the number in te polygons and in de point layer (tree clusters within the forest polygon). But I need to subtract the number of the (tree clusters) in the polygons.
I tried something like this to get the amount of tree clusters in the polygon, but it did not work:

```
aggregate( layer:='Aanplant_punt_v01', aggregate:='sum', expression:='amount', filter:= contains($geometry, geometry(@parent)))
```

I do not know if I'm thinking in the right direction.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your expression should be as follows:

```
aggregate( layer:='Aanplant_punt_v01', aggregate:='sum',
expression:="amount", filter:= within($geometry, geometry(@parent)))
```

the expression is a field and must be in double quotations, and the filter must be `within`, since your parentlayer is the polygon layer

Comment: Waaw super, thank you for the quick response. It works (I was almost there ;-) )